# How to insert data when we have Relationship constraints in MySQL database

Tags: mysql, sql, database, referential-integrity

I am following this [book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0133970779) for my database class. The database has 6 tables. From the 6 of them I will post two of the tables.

```
/*EMPLOYEE Table */
CREATE TABLE EMPLOYEE( 
    Fname VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,
    Minit CHAR,
    Lname VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,
    Ssn CHAR(9) NOT NULL,
    Bdate DATE,
    Address VARCHAR(30),
    Sex CHAR,
    Salary DECIMAL(10,2),
    Super_ssn CHAR(9),
    Dno INT NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (Ssn),
    FOREIGN KEY (Super_ssn) REFERENCES EMPLOYEE(Ssn)
    FOREIGN KEY (Dno) REFERENCES DEPARTMENT(Dnumber) );
```

Employee table has a recursive relation to demonstrate "an employee is a supervisor of another employee". It also references the DEPARTMENT table  to show that an employee works in a department. Below is the schema for the DEPARTMENT table.

```
CREATE TABLE DEPARTMENT( 
    Dname VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,
    Dnumber INT NOT NULL,
    Mgr_ssn CHAR(9) NOT NULL,
    Mgr_start_date DATE,
    PRIMARY KEY (Dnumber),
    UNIQUE (Dname),
    FOREIGN KEY (Mgr_ssn) REFERENCES EMPLOYEE(Ssn) 
    );
```

The DEPARTMENT table references the employee table to show that an employee manages a department.
When inserting data such as

```
    insert into EMPLOYEE values
    ('John','B','Smith','123456789','1965-01-09','731 Fondren, Houston, TX',
     'M',30000,'333445555',5);
```

We wont be able to execute the above query because there is a referential integrity `FOREIGN KEY (Super_ssn) REFERENCES EMPLOYEE(Ssn)`.  Same if i try the query below

```
insert into department values ('Research',5,'333445555','1988-05-22');
```

The above query wont execute because there is no data in employee table. My question is should we first insert the data and then alter the table and enforce referential integrity constraints. Or is there a way around. Your suggestions/advice will be appreciated. Thank You.

Comment: It doesn't need to be as drastic as dropping the constrain. Just allow the column to be null.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Foreign keys can have null values**. So you can enter the values that will, have foreign key value as **null**, like the topmost supervisor who will not have a supervisor above him.

So the general idea is to enter data bottom-up, like enter the values in the table that has no foreign key, then enter values on top of it referencing that table, and so on...


Exact approach would depend on the rest of the tables you are using in the example.

Comment: Thank you @Ankit Deshpande. This post I read do not really support foreign key having null values. Just got a little confused. Thanks for your responses though.

Comment: I agree with you.But then what happens in the case where the employee actually doesn't have a supervisor ??

Comment: Got your point @Ankit Deshpande. I have allowed null on my foreign key. Things are working fine. Thank you

Comment: I think this might help...
Imagine dept table without the supervisor id.
And create another table called deptSupervisor.
deptSupervisor will have deptID and empID of the supervisor.